# [Angular][Bootstrap] -Efeito collapse abrir e fechar com apenas um click

Tags: html5, angular, javascript-eventos, collapse

Estou querendo realizar um efeito de collapse no momento que altero de item no slider abaixo. Quando eu altero o item, eu recebo do serviço, varias informações recarregando meu componente filho (realizado um ngFor). Eu gostaria de fazer o efeito de fechar e abrir na mudança do item. Na documentação do bootsrap, eu tenho que realizar um click para fechar e outro para abrir. É possível com apenas um click (Alterando o item no slider) realizar o evento de abrir e fechar a div que está sendo renderizada ?

Caso tenham outro recurso de realizar a movimentação da div realizando o efeito de carregamento na navegação do slider, favor fiquem a vontade.

Estou utilizando o componente ng5-slider
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng5-slider

"(valueChange)" - realiza a chamada do meu método do serviço dentro da minha componente.ts para retorno dos dados.

[image: Slider]

Desde já agradeço pela atenção a todos.

[image: html do ng5-slider]

HTML do meu Slider

```
 <ng5-slider [(value)]="value"  (valueChange)="ServiceItem()" [options]="options"></ng5-slider>
```

Div que é renderizada na mudança durante a navegação do slider

```
  <div id="collapseExample">
    <div *ngFor="let itemLinhas of itens" class="card-block g-pa-0">
        <app-gridcoberturas [itensProdutos]="itemLinhas"></app-gridcoberturas>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

Comment: Posta o código como texto pra não precisar digitar isso tudo pra te ajudar...

Comment: @UpTI realizei atualização que voce solicitou. Desde já agradeço pelo o apoio. Por favor, veja se atende sua necessidade. Obrigado.

Comment: Alguma ideia pessoal ? @UpTI, posso ajudar em algo mais ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu utilizei uma lib chamada [`ngx-bootstrap`](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) e utilizei a component [collapse](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/collapse) para isso.

### ngx-bootstrap

O `Input collapse` é responsável por mostra/esconder os elementos. Então eu criei uma variável de controle para cada collapse.

```
  isColp3 = false;
  isColp4 = true
```

A estrutura básica do componente é assim

```
<div id="colp3" [collapse]="isColp3" class="card card-block card-header">
  <div class="well well-lg">Coisa aqui</div>
</div>
```

### ng5-slider

Com o `Output` `valueChange` eu chamo a minha função que irá mudar os collapses

Código html : `(valueChange)="mudaCollapse()"`

```
mudaCollapse() { 
    if( this.oldValue !== this.value){
      this.oldValue = this.value;
      this.isColp3 = !this.isColp3;
      this.isColp4 = !this.isColp4;
    }
  }
```

A condição `if( this.oldValue !== this.value)` é só para evitar que o `valueChange` execute quando se clica no botão.

O código completo pode ser visto neste [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3tyjw)